# How to split column header in DataGridView in c# windows application

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have to develop `DataGridView` program using stored table values. I like to show some specified columns on group column headers using column header split. Like

```
             Monthly Interest
-----------------------------------------
principal Interst  |  Interest  |    EMI 
----------------------------------------- 
                   |            |
```

Please help me.....

Comment: Please post the code  what you have been tried?

Comment: DGVs support neither spanning row or columns nor grouping.

Comment: You can only do something like this by [manually painting the header cell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35323076/3773066) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do the trick:

```
for (i=0; i <textString.Length; i++){
  if (textString.Length > 1 && textString[i] != null)
      addRow.Cells[i].Value = textString[i];
}
```

Comment: you can refer this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dversch/creating-a-multiple-column-header-within-datagridview/