# Merging DataGrid Column Headers with Specific Range

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

First, i'd like to apologize if this question happens to be a duplicate. But as far as i would like to ask for help, i'd like to know of any function or code or walkthrough on how i can merge a ColumnHeader of a DataGridView from a specific column range.

ie: Lastname, Firstname, and Middlename are under the "NAME" Merged Header. Company, and Position is under the "WORK" Merged Header.

please do note that both the "NAME" / "WORK" and "LASTNAME" / "FIRSTNAME" / "MIDDLENAME" / "COMPANY" / "POSITION" are all headers too. So Basically, i would have two (2) lines of ColumnHeaders.

PS: i've already searched a couple of times in several forums and collaboration sites but i can't seem to make it work as they all give a constant of two (2) span range. and i've also managed to stumble across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366436/how-can-merge-a-particular-column-header-in-datagridview-c), but it doesn't seem to work and suffice my requirement.

looking forward to a appreciative helps. thank you

[image]

Comment: [Merge RTL Datagridview columns header in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286666/merge-rtl-datagridview-columns-header-in-c-sharp) This should get you going!

Comment: This is also a good one [how to merge headers in a DataGridView](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/87004d70-482a-4b86-ba18-371670254b6a/how-to-merge-headers-in-a-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Comment: So you are trying to get sub-headers or columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it customizing the DataGridView. Here is a sample:

```
public DgvColumnHeaderMerge()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

private void DgvColumnHeaderMerge_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("JanWin", "Win");
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("JanLoss", "Loss");
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("FebWin", "Win");
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("FebLoss", "Loss");
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MarWin", "Win");
   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MarLoss", "Loss");

   for (int j = 0; j < this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
   {
     this.dataGridView1.Columns[j].Width = 45;
   }

   this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
   this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight * 2;
   this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment .BottomCenter;
}
```

For more, see this link - [Sub-headers in DataGridView](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/531577e8-0be3-406d-a81b-48f8ed02e8df/multiline-merged-datagridview-header?forum=winformsdatacontrols)