# Merging column name of Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am adding data to a datatable. Data is added according to column header. Once the data is added, I want to merge the only the column header. Is it possible? Below is the example.

**Input**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Comment: No. It is not possible. You need to merge it when you shows at the front-end.

Comment: I would say just once the table has finished drawing, Remove the current `thead` and add a new one with the way you want.

Comment: This question is not clear. Where do yo want to merge the data? In the DataTable? When you show it in a DataGrid for example? Please edit your question, clarify this points and add any relevant code.

Comment: Look this, was worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286666/merge-rtl-datagridview-columns-header-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Pikoh I think, the question is quite clear when you look at the images.