# How to get the string length in terms of pixel to center the string in a merge cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to measure the width of a string to center it in the cell.
I created a function to merge column in datagridview by using `Graphics.DrawString`

Let:

```
mergedHeaderWidth  --> with of the new cell
xCord --> x coordinate of the cell
xCordFinal --> target x coordinate to center the string
stringWidth --> width of the string in pixel <-- *this is my question*

to get the final coordinate where to start drawing the string we will subtract the half the width of the  string to the half the string of the cell width plus the location of the cell.

xCordFinal = xCord + (mergedHeaderWidth / 2) - (stringWidth / 2);

int xCordFinal = xCord + mergedHeaderWidth / 2;
//Draw the merged Header Column Text.
 e.Graphics.DrawString("Address Test", dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font, 
Brushes.Black, xCordFinal, yCord + 3);
```

[image]

Comment: [Graphics.MeasureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). Try the [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer?view=net-5.0) class to draw the text, it has a [MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext?view=net-5.0) static method.

Comment: Best use a centered StringFormat and use the combined cell bounds as the Rectangle!

Comment: ...or `TextFomatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFomatFlags.HorizontalCenter` with TextRenderer. As TaW mentioned, use a Rectangle as the reference bounds of your strings, not a Point.

Comment: Just to echo what TaW said, [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323076/3773066).

Comment: note: add the font you are using to the MeasureString method to get a more accurate measurement

Comment: Just curiosity: Why can't you use `DataGridViewCellStyle.Alignment`? Can't you just set it to value `DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter`?